# Appending new image DOM object to a <div>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

I'm trying to append a new image DOM object to a `div` but it is not including any of the image DOM's attributes.

```
 $linkedImage = $('<a></a>', {href: "javascript:void"})
               .addClass('myNextImage')
               .append('<img />', {alt: "MyImage", src: $imageURL});
 this._div.append($linkedImage);
```

What this shows up as is:

```
<a href="javascript:void" class="myNextImage"><img></a>
```

Without the alt and src tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before you append it create the image element like you did with the anchor element.

```
 $linkedImage = $('<a></a>', {href: "javascript:void"})
               .addClass('myNextImage')
               .append($('<img />', {alt: "MyImage", src: $imageURL}));
 this._div.append($linkedImage)
```